# why are my check marks being printed funky from SSRS to PDF?

Tags: pdf, reporting-services

In preview mode:

[image]

In PDF:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I'm using an icon by the way:

[image]

Comment: what font are you using for the checkmarks? Wingdings?

Comment: Yes! They need to be check marks because if it's something else and I have to deal with visibility, it'll mess up all the other items on the report by pushing things around and all items need to be static on the report.

Comment: There was a known bug related to this, which could affect you if you were using an unupdated or old version of SSRS : https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/431057/ssrs-2008-sp1-ctp-pdf-export-of-wingdings-characters-above-char-127-fails

Comment: Sorry, maybe I said it wrong. I'm using the Gauge Data indicator and the icon is a check mark. I edited my post with a screenshot.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there, though I know there are some issues with printing indicators. Take a look at this post for some alternatives: http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2012/08/04/displaying-checkboxes-in-an-ssrs-report/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem with resizing.

Not sure if it will work for you but place the indicator inside a fixed size rectangle placeholder inside the tablix text box.

[image]